# Restrict internet access at specified times

Tags: c#

I'm trying to do a parental control software project. I blocked specific websites and unblocked them by using host file. Later on, I tried to disable/enable internet access by disabling and enabling LAN connection programatically. Is there any way to block internet access at certain time in C# such as `8 January 2013` between `20.00`-`23.00` hours. Date and hours are chosen by parents. How can I do this by using user's computer's time in C# ?

Comment: Are you trying to restrict internet access for the entire computer (e.g. Internet Explorer) or just your application?

Comment: I am trying to restrict internet access for the entire computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Windows Service](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C) which will periodically check the computer time and do whatever tasks you choose accordingly.

Another option is to schedule tasks that will run at certain times.

It seems you already researched *how* to do this, disabling the LAN or changing the hosts are both ways that will impact the user's ability to use the internet... Disabling the LAN connection will give a full block where as modifying HOST is actually just a *[blacklist](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2011/01/whitelisting_vs.html)* ...

Comment: Yes i used hosts file as a blacklist for specific websites. And i disabled internet access of entire computer with a disabling LAN connection code. I want to take time variables from parents and use it in my disabling LAN connection code.

Comment: Then sounds like creating a windows service is your best approach... Here is an [example](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ajifocus/AppScheduler05262006074807AM/AppScheduler.aspx?ArticleID=b52f76da-943f-4807-9675-869f135ef2cd)